# Nested lists and dictonaries

Tags: python

I have to read contents of a file and print them with string formatting.Currently I am using a dict with the values of the keys being a list i.e list nested withing a dict.

```
data={'Hour':[],'Total Incoming':[],'Pass':[],'Stale Client':[],'Error':[],'Exec time':[[],],'Update time':[[],]}
```

While printing I use a for loop

```
for i in range (0,len(data['Hour']-1):
    print data['Hour'][i],data['Total Incoming'][i] and so on
```

I have a doubt if a dict nested within list is more optimized and better than the above

```
data=[{'Hour1':['Total Incoming','Pass','Stale Client','Error','Exec time'[],'Update time'[]]},{'Hour2':['Total Incoming','Pass','Stale Client','Error','Exec time'[],'Update time'[]]...}
```

Can you help me in this regard

Comment: Have you tried using the `timeit` module?

Comment: Both the methods have the same time for execution as one is a list within dict and other is dicts within list.Well I actually wanted to know which one is better way for storing the data read and printing the values out from it as the files i am reading are around 3 to 4 gb in size and the count of total incoming is around 5000 per hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really makes no difference in terms of memory optimisation whether you use a list in a dict or a dict in a list.  Depending on you use case, one may be easier to work with that the other, in which case you may get a small overall speed performance by choosing a specific one.